# httpclient 4.x repeating query string params

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

thanks for reading.

I'm trying to call an IBM REST API which requires that a query string parameter be repeated. In this particular case, to perform a search requires you to pass in the "condition" query string parameter for each condition.

For example,

http:/.../rest/search?condition=name|NotEquals|sublimemm&condition=age|LessThan|30

Using the URIBuilder in the latest apache http client, this would be done like this:

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("http").setHost(host).setPort(port).setPath(restPath + searchUri)
    .setParameter("condition", "taskActivityName|RouteHumanTask")
    .setParameter("condition", "taskStatus|NotEquals|Closed");

    HttpPost post = getHttpPostMethod(builder.build());
```

The problem is that URIBuilder will add the query string parameter "condition" with a value, and then overwrite it with the second value. It's using a map internally which is keyed off the parameter name, so it seems impossible to use this class for this particular use case.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an option I can set on the URIBuilder to get around this? Any ideas?

Thanks StackOverflow,
Sublimemm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `URIBuilder#addParameter` instead of `URIBuilder#setParameter`.